# In GCD domain every invertible ideal is principal

Tags: commutative-algebra

This is the exercise in the book *Commutative Rings* by Kaplansky.

> Prove that in a GCD domain every invertible ideal is principal.

I'm looking for some hints.

**Edit**

After understanding the hint, here is my approach:

Let $I$ be an invertible ideal of a GCD domain $R$. Because $I$ is finitely generated as $R$-module we can write $I=(a_1/b_1,...,a_n/b_n)R$, where $a_i, b_i$ are elements in $R$.

Since $R$ is a GCD domain we can choose $a_i, b_i$ such that $(a_i,b_i)=1$.

By hypothesis $R$ is also an LCM domain. Let $c$ be the least common multiple of $b_i$'s, $d$ be the greatest common divisor of $a_i$'s. It is easy to see that $I^{-1}=(c/d)R$.

Because of invertibility there exist $m_i$'s of $I$ such that $m_1(c/d)+\cdots+m_n(c/d)=1$.

We conclude that $I=uR$, where $u=m_1+\cdots+m_n$, for if $x\in I$, $x=x\cdot1=xm_1(c/d)+\cdots+xm_n(c/d)=x(c/d)u$.

Comment: An integral domain is called GCD domain if any two its elements have a greatest common divisor.

Comment: @Axlp1210 Hint: $I^{-1}=d^{-1}R$ where $d$ is..., you know.

Comment: Actually you can start with $I\subseteq R$.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you. I love that kind of hint. It got me think seriously to understand how things work.