# Flatness of $\frac{R[T]}{I}$ over $R$ implies that $I$ is principal or $I=R[T]$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, flatness

Let $R$ be a UFD, and let $I$ be an ideal of $R[T]$ ($T$ is a variable over $R$). Assume that $\frac{R[T]}{I}$ is a flat $R$-module.

The following claim and its proof appear in the comments to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319091/a-generalization-of-nagatas-flatness-theorem) question.

**Claim:** 
If $I$ is proper, then $I$ is principal.

**Proof:** Let $A=R[T]$, then $A$ is also a UFD, since $R$ is. 
So, any ideal $I=Jf$ where $J$ has height at least two. We wish to show that if $A/I$ is $R$-flat, then $J=A$. 
If not, you have an exact sequence, $0 \rightarrow A/J \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} A/I \rightarrow A/fA \rightarrow 0$. 
But, height of $J$ is at least two implies $J \cap R \neq 0$. 
Then, for any $0 \neq a \in J \cap R$, we get $A/I \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} A/I$ is non-injective, contradicting flatness. Thus $J=A$ and then $I=fA$, a principal ideal.

> **Question:** Why any ideal $I$ of $A$ is of the form $I=Jf$, where $J$ is an ideal of $A$ of height at least two and $f \in A$.

**Another proof of the claim, based on a result of Ohm and Rush:** It seems that the above claim can be proved also by a result of Ohm and Rush, [Corollary 1.3](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183533044), which says the following:
$\frac{R[T]}{I}$ is $R$-flat if and only if $I$ is an [invertible](https://digitalcommons.lsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1849&context=gradschool_disstheses) ideal and $c(I)=R$.

So we should show that an invertible ideal of $R[T]$ is a principal ideal of $R[T]$; this is indeed true since in a GCD domain, invertible ideals are principal, and of course a UFD is a GCD domain, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218061/in-gcd-domain-every-invertible-ideal-is-principal) question.

Notice that in the paper of Ohm and Rush $R$ is just a commutative ring, not necessarily an integral domain.
Invertible ideals in integral domains are dealt with in [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387900896) book of Zariski and Samuel, for example.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If $I$ has height $2$ or more then we can set $J = I$ and $f = 1$.  For the zero ideal set $f = 0$, so all that remains are the height $1$ ideals.  If $I$ is prime then because we're in a UFD height $1$ ideals are principal, so we set $f$ to be the generating element and $J = A$.  All that leaves is non-prime ideals of height $1$.

Comment: @Jim, thank you for your (almost complete) answer! Please, what if $I$ is non-prime  of height $1$? There exists a maximal ideal $M$ such that $I \subsetneq M$ ($I \neq M$ since $I$ is assumed to be non-prime, and a maximal ideal is of course prime). How to continue?

Comment: Hint. Write $I=Jf$, where $\gcd(J)=1$.

Comment: @user26857, thank you for the hint! (Hopefully, in a day or two I will think about it, and let you know if I have or have not succeeded to see the proof).